# Async function runs in a sync (serial) way, tasks block each other

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I do not get any acceleration using asyncio. This snippet still runs the same fashion as a sync job. Most of the examples use asyncio.sleep() to impose delay, my question is what if part of the code poses the delay depending on the input parameters.

```
async def c(n):
    #this loop is supposed to impose delay
    for i in range(1, n * 40000):
        c *= i
   return n

async def f():
    tasks = [c(i) for i in [2,1,3]]
    r=[]
    completed, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    for item in completed:
        r.append(item.result())

    return r

if __name__=="__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    k=loop.run_until_complete(f())
    loop.close()
```

I expect to get [1,2,3] but I do not (there is no time difference when running in serial also)

Comment: You have misunderstood `asyncio`. It is using only one thread, so for CPU bound processes, such as your `for` loop, with no IO, you will not gain anything from using it. Function `c(n)` never yields the CPU, since there is no IO call (or explicit yield), thus the other code calls never get a chance to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

asyncio is not about getting acceleration, it's about avoiding "callback hell" when programming in an asynchronous environment, such as (but not limited to) non-blocking IO. Since the code in the question is not asynchronous, there is nothing to gain from using asyncio - but you can look into `multiprocessing` instead.

In the above case, the function is defined as async, but it runs its entire calculation without awaiting anything. It also contains references to unassigned variables, so let's start with a version that runs:

```
async def long_calc(n):
    p = 1
    for i in range(1, n * 10000):
        p *= i
    print(math.log(p))
    return p
```

The `print` at the end immediately indicates when the calculation is done. Starting several such coroutines "in parallel" is done with `asyncio.gather`:

```
async def wait_calcs():
    return await asyncio.gather(*[long_calc(i) for i in [2, 1, 3]])
```

`asyncio.gather` will let the calculations run and return once all of them are complete, returning a list of their results in the order in which they they appear in the argument list. But the output printed when running `loop.run_until_complete(wait_calcs())` shows that calculations are not really running in parallel:

```
178065.71824964616
82099.71749644238
279264.3442843094
```

The results correspond to the `[2, 1, 3]` order. If the coroutines were running  in parallel, the smallest number would appear first because its coroutine has by far the least work to do.

We can force the coroutine to give a chance to other coroutines to run by introducing a no-op sleep in the inner loop:

```
async def long_calc(n):
    p = 1
    for i in range(1, n * 10000):
        p *= i
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print(math.log(p))
    return p
```

The output now shows that the coroutines were running in parallel:

```
82099.71749644238
178065.71824964616
279264.3442843094
```

Note that this version also takes more time to run because it involves more switching between the coroutines and the main loop. The slowdown can be avoided by only sleeping once in a hundred cycles or so.